# Access IIS site from internet

Tags: iis

I just created a site in C# that I host in IIS6, it can be used locally but I'd like to configure it so users can access to it from the web. The client has provided me a public IP that I tried to setup to the site in IIS but it did not work so I guess is not enough, I'm not a network expert so I would appreciate your help.

Comment: You have no provided enough information about the setup to explain the reason the website isn't accessible.  Have you forwarded the port?

Comment: I have not made any kind of configuration since my knowledge in this matter is ver y minimal, I was hoping to get some steps and start from that. The windows firewall has the port 80 open and I just tried binding the public IP to the IIS site with no luck.

Comment: @saman0suke You will need assistance from your network manager.  Ask them to make the IIS server available to the internet using the IP provided.  If you are without expertise, then do not take making something available to the internet lightly, make sure someone with security knowledge validates it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you will need to do a port forwarding.

Guides for lots of routers for this can be found at http://portforward.com/.  This should list most brands of routers.  What you will need to do is setup a port forward which sends port 80 (HTTP) or 443 (HTTPS) to the internal IP of the machine that the site is hosted on.

You will also need to make sure that the windows firewall for this machine is either disabled or has a rule in it allowing inbound web traffic.

Comment: When you mean "To the internal IP of the machine that the site is hosted on" you mean the IP address that I get from the network adapter when I run "ipconfig" in CMD? besides that, the server needs to have access to internet to allow incoming connections right? Thanks!